# comparing UTC date times

Tags: php

Let's say I am accepting a string with a value = `2013-05-17T19:22Z` ( this is an UTC date time format)

I can get my current time using `gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z");`

How do I compare date time in php?

here's what i want to do:

My function is receiving a date and time and I need to compare that time with my current time, and if the time received is 1 hour less than the current time, it returns false.

Something like:

```
function expire(var $dateTime){
  if ( $dateTime < 60min of my current time ){
   return false;
  }
  else{
   return true;
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I just want to know how to compare 2 UTC formatted date times.

How do you compare `2013-05-17T19:22Z` and `2013-05-17T20:22Z` ?

And how to know whenever the difference of both times is 1 hour or less?

Answer (score 1):

try like this

```
<?php
$date1 = new DateTime("now");
$date2 = new DateTime("tomorrow");
var_dump($date1 == $date2);
var_dump($date1 < $date2);
var_dump($date1 > $date2);
?>
```

or refer [THIS](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the same timezone for all times you want to compare. Then, I'd rather use numeric representation of the time (milliseconds) which simplifies all the operations.